# Type function prototype in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

Typescript: How can i add type for function with prototype?

```
interface Fool {
  greet(): any;
}

function Fool(name: string) {
  this.name = name;
}

Fool.prototype.greet = function() {
  console.log(`Fool greets ${this.name}`);
};

Fool('Joe').greet();
`Property 'greet' does not exist on type 'void'.`;
```

Comment: Are you missing `new`?

Comment: Why don't you use a class instead?

Answer (score 4):

If constructing the instance with `new` suits:

```
interface Fool {
  name: string;
  greet(): void;
}

interface FoolConstructor {
  new (name: string): Fool;
  (): void;
}

const Fool = function(this: Fool, name: string) {
  this.name = name;
} as FoolConstructor;

Fool.prototype.greet = function() {
  console.log(`Fool greets ${this.name}`);
};

new Fool('Joe').greet();
```

Answer (score 2):

With this solution, you can use both `Fool(name)` and `new Fool(name)`.

```
interface Fool {
  name: string;
  greet(): void;
}

interface FoolConstructor {
  new(name: string): Fool;
  (name: string): Fool;
}

const Fool = function (this: Fool | void, name: string): Fool {
  if (!(this instanceof Fool)) {
    return new Fool(name);
  }

  this.name = name;
  return this;
} as FoolConstructor;

Fool.prototype.greet = function(this: Fool) {
  console.log(`Fool greets ${this.name}`);
};

console.log(
  new Fool('Joe').greet(),
  Fool('Joe').greet()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

In case of node.js and deno you need to compare with `undefined` instead of `Window`

```js
interface Fool {
    greet(): any;
}


function Fool(this: any, name: string): Fool {
    if (this === undefined) { // check if it was called statically.
        return new (Fool as any)(name);
    }
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}

Fool.prototype.greet = function () {
    console.log(`Fool greets ${this.name}`);
};

Fool("Joe").greet(); // Fool greets Joe
```

**ORIGINAL**

The right way in TS is to use classes instead of `prototype`. Then you don't need to tackle this problem.

```js
class Fool {
  constructor(public name: string) {}

  greet() {
      console.log(`Fool greets ${this.name}`);
  }  
}

new Fool("Joe").greet(); // Fool greets Joe
```

If you still want to use prototype, what isn't recommended, you can do a hotfix:

```js
interface Fool {
  greet(): any;
}


function Fool(this: any, name: string): Fool {
  if (this.constructor === Window) { // check if it was called statically.
    return new (Fool as any)(name);
  }
  this.name = name;
  return this;
}

Fool.prototype.greet = function () {
  console.log(`Fool greets ${this.name}`);
};

Fool("Joe").greet(); // Fool greets Joe
```

Comment: That is not true. You can always use the `constructor function` pattern. It is less used, but stil valid. Vf the section talking about `constructor function` in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html. What is needed in the example is only the `new` keyboard.

Comment: What is not true? And where did I say it isn't valid? all js is valid for ts, it's just not the right way.

Comment: is it possible run it with ts-node , not in browser                                
 ```                                                                                                                                 ts-node "/Users/vaclav.benes/Git/typescript/typescript_samples/learn/proto.ts"
/Users/vaclav.benes/Git/typescript/typescript_samples/learn/proto.ts:17
Fool("Joe").greet(); // Fool greets Joe
            ^
TypeError: Fool(...).greet is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vaclav.benes/Git/typescript/typescript_samples/learn/proto.ts:17:13)
)```

Comment: for browser you need to use `tsc` to compile .ts into .js, then you can run it from browser too, TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript. You can't run without compilation. ts-node does it on the fly.

Comment: For example here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28TQN4ChrWPAdhALgE4Cuw+8hAFAA7EBGIAlsNDmALYCmAXNAYYxwBzAJSoAvmgzQhhTp3yUx6TKqy4ISTgDoQ8IZQAGCJDLkKYAEhT4AFowja2XcYZEBuaeMxpJaHJwA7nCIIJQARABS8JzhItqy8ooe0AD0qSGmiRbQ0ZxAA you can see on the right side JS version of TS and you can run this JS version in browser.

Comment: All right, my goal is run `Fool("Joe").greet()` not in browser but with nodejs server or deno or ts-node. Like this 
[Link](http://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=7&pln=20&pc=4)

Comment: Aha, I see, I'll update the answer soon with a ts-node.

Comment: Done, the last example is for node.js env.

Comment: Cool with ts-node works. Btw global is part of nodejs ?  I play with deno.land [deno.land](www.deno.land) and there is no global.

Comment: global is window in node.js, not sure about deno, perhaps they block access to it, at least they mention it in their docs for webassembly https://deno.land/typedoc/classes/webassembly.global.html

Comment: Try `if (!(this instanceof Fool)) {` instead of global, should work too.

Comment: my bad this is correct https://repl.it/repls/PaleGraveRectangle , `undefined` . sorry for spam.