# How can I convert an object constructor from javascript to work in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I am learning TypeScript by converting a vanilla JS toto list project to React + TypeScript.

In my old code, I had an object constructor `Project` that worked just fine:

```
function Project(title) {
  this.title = title;
  this.tasks = {};
}
```

As I try to implement this same constructor in TypeScript it seems like TS doesn't like my use of the word `this`. It underlines both `this` statements in red and hovering over it gives me the error:

```
'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
```

I tried adding types to it like so:

```
this.title: string = title;
title: string = title;
```

Both give me the error:

```
'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

My main question is how would I write this same object constructor to work in TypeScript? What am I doing wrong with `this`? I have tried googling the problem but I don't see anything about this issue specifically on stack overflow or the typescript docs.

It looks like you can still make classes in typescript but I have tried to avoid them since 1) They aren't "real" in javascript, just syntactical sugar, and 2) I'd like to learn how to implement object constructors in TypeScript out of sheer intellectual curiosity, if possible.

Comment: can you add [mcve]

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to get typescript to run in a JS fiddle but I will see what I can do.

Comment: have a read in here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61867798/type-function-prototype-in-typescript

Comment: I was talking about js [mcve] then what you tried in ts

Answer (score 2):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters

In a method or function definition, an initial parameter named this has special meaning in TypeScript. These parameters are erased during compilation:

```
// TypeScript input with 'this' parameter
function fn(this: SomeType, x: number) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use class to solve the problem:

```js
class Project {
  tasks: Record<string, unknown> = {}
  
  constructor(public title: string) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it but as per my question I was also asking if it were possible to solve this without using class. Just honestly curious.

Comment: @manski it is possible but why don't you want to use `class` in my experience it is about several times faster than using `function` and `this`

Comment: honestly just intellectual curiosity. I have my answer though, I went ahead and just committed to using class.